# Outputs of GlobalAveragePooling2D same dimensions as input (Keras)

Tags: python, keras

when using a GlobalAveragePoolingLayer2D() in Keras, the dimension of the output is of course not the dimension of the output, for example if the input dimension is (100,100,64), the output dimension is (1,1,64). But I would like to have the same output dimension. There are two options which work for me: reproduce the mean of every channel 100*100 times in the given channel in the output or just place the result at a given position in the 100x100 matrix according to this output channel and placing zeros at all other positions. Does someone have an idea how to do this?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Lambda layer which wraps arbitrary function as a Layer object.

```
# Replacing layer values with it's mean:
def lambda_layer(x):
    a = K.zeros_like(x) + K.mean(x, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
    return a

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16,3, input_shape=(50,50,3)))
model.add(Lambda(lambda_layer))

'''
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 16)        448       
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)            (None, 48, 48, 16)        0         
=================================================================
'''
```

Similarly you can place mean at one location, keeping zeros for rest of the values.

Comment: @SteC if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.